# How to prove that $H-M$ has at least one interior point, provided that $H$ and $M$ are both convex and at least one of them has an interior point?

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof of **Extended Hyperplane Separation Theorem** in Peter. D. Lax's book, there is a statement without proof that since $H$ and $M$ are disjoint convex subsets of linear space $X$, and at least one of them has an interior point, so does $K = H - M$. I consider that if both of $H$ and $M$ contain one interior point, denoted by $x_0$ and $y_0$ separately, then we can prove $x_0-y_0$ is interior point of $K$. But I can't figure out how to verify the statement if only one of $H$ and $K$ contains an interior point. Is there any hint on proving this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say $M$ contains an open set $U$ with interior point $u$. Fix any $h_0\in H$. Then
$$
h_0 - u \in \{h_0\} - U \subseteq H-M.
$$
As $\{h_0\} - U$ is open, $h_0-u$ is an interior point of $H-M$.

EDIT ------ after clarifying the author's definition of an interior point:

$u$ is an interior point of $M$ is for every $y\in X$ exist an $\varepsilon>0$ (depending on $y$) such that $u+ty\in M$ for every $|t|<\varepsilon$.

Ok, now if  $u$ is an interior point of $M$, obviously $-u$ is an interior point of $-M$.

Now let's verify, that $h_0 -u$ is an interior point of $K = H-M$. Let $y\in X$. Then there
is some $\varepsilon>0$ with $-u + ty \subset -M$ for every $|t|<\varepsilon$. Hence $h_0 -u + ty \in H-M = K$.

Comment: I only learned functional analysis on metric spaces so I have no idea what does *open set* mean in Topological space. In Lax's book, it says $x$ is an interior point when $\forall y \in K$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $|t| < \epsilon$, $x+ty \in K$. Is it possible to derive the conclusion starting from this definition?

Comment: I just googled the book you mentioned, on page 123 there is a theorem basically listing all properties of _open sets_ you need for the above. In addition, you use a very rare definition for interior points: "Standard" would be: $x$ is an interior point of $K$ if for some $\varepsilon>0$ you have $B_\varepsilon \subseteq K$, where $B_\varepsilon=\{x\in X| d(x,0)<\varepsilon\}$. Using this definition, it would be easier for me to start from here.

Comment: The definition you use is the open set in *metric space*. However, in proving the hyperplane separation theorem, the author has not introduced metric space yet. I feel strange with such definition for interior point at the first glance too. I am looking for the proof without assumption of metric or normed space.

Comment: BTW, such "strange" definition is useful in proving the following property of Minkowski functional: $p_K(x) < 1$ iff $x$ is an interior point of $K$, where $K$ is convex and absorbing. I think that's why the author define interior point in this way.

Comment: Hmm, difficult. Using the strange definition, every point of the set $K=(0,1)\times\{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ would be an interior point of $K$, but it is not in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ahh, and I rechecked your definition, it is not every $y\in K$ but every $y\in X$ !!!

Comment: Ahh!!I see.. I made a terrible mistake... You are right, and it's quite straightforward using the correct definition. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!